# clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am getting the following errors when I try to start react-native

```
gis00109@GIS00109 ~ % npx react-native start     
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_kernel.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_platform.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_pthread.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libc++abi.tbd) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_kernel_host.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_platform_host.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_pthread_host.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:72:
../src/thread.cc:36:25: error: unknown type name 'ConstFSEventStreamRef'
void HandleStreamEvents(ConstFSEventStreamRef stream, void *ctx, size_t ...
                        ^
../src/thread.cc:36:108: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamEventFlags'
  ...stream, void *ctx, size_t numEvents, void *eventPaths, const FSEventStre...
                                                                  ^
../src/thread.cc:36:152: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamEventId'
  ...*eventPaths, const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[], const FSEventSt...
                                                                    ^
../src/thread.cc:54:3: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamContext'
  FSEventStreamContext context = { 0, ctx, NULL, NULL, NULL };
  ^
../src/thread.cc:56:3: error: unknown type name 'FSEventStreamRef'
  FSEventStreamRef stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, &HandleStreamEvent...
  ^
../src/thread.cc:56:98: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow'
  ...&HandleStreamEvents, &context, fse->paths, kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow...
                                                ^
6 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gis00109/.npm/_npx/31282/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Please share more about what is your environment and what do u really want to ask. Sharing a running log only dose not explain anything

Comment: im getting npm is error I do no how to clear this error i can t even start npm and run in ios app whatever i start or run npm means its come like (using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot] ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file) in terminal and im using mac os and it is react native

Comment: npx means you are running a package bin from node_modules. This is installed by npm. Try to rebuild the package. Delete node_modules and run npm install

Comment: i do not how to delete node modules this is first time im using this enviroment

Comment: please guide me to delete node modules and install process in react native